# How to import data files from a different directory Python 3.6

Tags: directory, python-3.6

I just converted over from Matlab to python and having trouble trying to open a .csv file stored in a different directory just for that particular project. in Matlab we can use adddpath to access a different directory in 1 line. I cant seem to find a particular function for this. So far I have tried this but python isnt able to find the file. I cant seem to find relevant functions in other threads as well. What is the issue? Appreciate your help!

```
import csv
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Desktop\\Coding Projects\\data')

with open('sph.csv', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    data_read = [row for row in reader]

print(data_read)
```

Comment: open(r'C:\\Desktop\\Coding Projects\\data\\sph.csv','r')

Comment: Thanks alot @Silencer !